# Photoshop CS5: Subtract/exclude a vector mask from an existing mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes

I am attempting to create very simple icon, which resembles a 'dashboard' of a car.

The first part of the icon (shape 1) was created by adding and subtracting shapes. The second part (shape 2) was created because the three parts of the shape needed to be placed accurately.

Is there a way to subtract shape 2 from shape 1? I am aware that shapes can be combined, but can they be "excluded" together?

Here's shape 1:

[image]

and here's the second shape that I want to subtract from the first:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using Illustrator for this type of work, not Photoshop.

Comment: I would agree, the designers use illustrator, but I'm not a designer and only know Photoshop (no time to learn another design tool). Just needed it for one job while the designer was away.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Select the path of shape 2 on its layer. Copy the path.
2. Target the shape 1 layer.
3. Paste.
4. Activate a shape tool (rectangle, ellipse, doesn't matter).
5. On the control panel, click the "Subtract" icon (second from left).
6. Turn off or discard the shape 2 layer.

Not nearly as simple or intuitive as it would be in a native vector application like Illustrator, but it'll get you there.

Comment: excellent answer, although my question is, why *aren't* you using Illustrator, Greg?

Comment: LOL! I so carefully refrained from saying that! :-D

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum I know, I know ... but I have learned Photoshop, and just needed it for this one small task.

Comment: Learned how to use a hammer and suddenly everything's a nail, eh? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! What would you recommend if I wanted to apply a different "feather" to the vectors?