# How to intersect existing shapes in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I'm trying to intersect 2 existing shapes in Photoshop (CS6). I've found tutorials that allow me to intersect at the time of putting the second shape down, but nothing that allows me to do so with shapes already in the document.

The reason I would like this is that I would like to "tweak" the position of the second shape, by nudging it, adjusting its size etc. The only way I can do this at the moment is by undoing to remove the second shape, and starting again.

**Is there a way to intersect 2 shapes that are already in the page?**

(In Photoshop, not Illustrator. I don't have access to Illustrator at the moment)

Comment: Duplicate question ? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/photoshop-cs5-subtract-exclude-a-vector-mask-from-an-existing-mask?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a shape, in a form of two basic shapes partially substracted?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-to-create-a-shape-in-a-form-of-two-basic-shapes-partially-substracted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately it's pretty simple.

1. Create new document and create two shapes.
2. Choose "Path Selection Tool"
3. Select any shape.
4. Ctrl + x (or Cmd + x)
5. Select the second shape using "Path Selection Tool"
6. Ctrl + v (or Cmd + v)
7. Intersect Shape Areas (look at blue circle on options bar)

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you if you could explain the shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

Try to deal with this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGSzm4xaDfI or use vector masks.

[image]

Comment: This video doesn't answer my question: it combines the shapes at the time of putting the second shape down. Also, I think it's better to answer the question here on the site, and not depend completely on external resources (although links to external sites in addition to an answer here I believe are fine).

Comment: But there is no pathfinder in Photoshop! I give you two tips!

Comment: Although maybe poor in quality, @benoît does mention vector masks and posted a screenshot to how you might set it up. The vector mask itself would act as the intersecting shape and can be edited later.

Comment: Screenshot was after the first comment…